# How to Sum all of the values in a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sum

I have a collection in mongo of students with grades in math,writing, and reading. I need to sum all of the math, writing, and reading grades.

For Instance if 3 students each got 50 in Math then the sum would be 150.

So far I have:

db.student.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":null, total:{$sum:"$math score"}}}])

I have been on Google for about an hour trying to figure this out. I have zero experience using mongo, so it has been slow going.

Here is a sample of my data

```
{
 "student_data":
 [
  {
   "S-ID": 91371,
   "gender": "male",
   "race/ethnicity": "group B",
   "parental level of education": "some college",
   "lunch": "standard",
   "test preparation course": "completed",
   "math score": 44,
   "reading score": 50,
   "writing score": 48,
   "Total Score": 142
},
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample db data so that I can have an idea of how data is stored

Comment: I've added some sample data, I think I am getting messed up because the data is inside an array.

Comment: I have added a answer please to check it @hunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("testX");

function show(c,emit=true) {
  var nn = 0;
  c.forEach(function(r) {
        nn++;
        if(emit == true) {
            printjson(r);
        }
    });
print("found " + nn);
};

db.foo.drop(); // CAREFUL! This drops "foo" every time!

var students = [
            {_id:1, studentId:"A1", math:10, writing:15, reading: 17}
           ,{_id:2, studentId:"A2", math:12, writing:17, reading: 19}
           ,{_id:3, studentId:"A3", math:14, writing:19, reading: 21}
           ,{_id:4, studentId:"A4", math:16, writing:21, reading: 23}
            ];

db.foo.insert(students);

c = db.foo.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: null, totMath: {$sum: "$math"}, totWrite: {$sum: "$writing"}, totRead: {$sum: "$reading"}}}
                  ]);

show(c, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having such a data in db as follows

```
     {"student_data":[{
       "S-ID": 91371,
       "gender": "male",
       "race/ethnicity": "group B",
       "parental level of education": "some college",
       "lunch": "standard",
       "test preparation course": "completed",
       "math score": 44,
       "reading score": 50,
       "writing score": 48,
       "Total Score": 142
    },{
       "S-ID": 91371,
       "gender": "male",
       "race/ethnicity": "group B",
       "parental level of education": "some college",
       "lunch": "standard",
       "test preparation course": "completed",
       "math score": 44,
       "reading score": 50,
       "writing score": 48,
       "Total Score": 142
    },{
       "S-ID": 91371,
       "gender": "male",
       "race/ethnicity": "group B",
       "parental level of education": "some college",
       "lunch": "standard",
       "test preparation course": "completed",
       "math score": 44,
       "reading score": 50,
       "writing score": 48,
       "Total Score": 142
    }]



   db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'student_data'},
    {$group:
    {_id:'null',
    {count:{$sum:$math score}
    }}
    }])
```

Comment: When I run the command I get an error  [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):5:4. I also made sure to change collection to the actual collection name.

Comment: I attempted the same command in python and recieved [{'_id': None, 'total': 0}]

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to add $student_data.math scores in the group. Thanks for the help.